# IOS frequently called camera to collapse

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I called frequently camera in the application of continuous calls to photograph 80 times or so, the application will crash.Why is that?

Comment: I believe there is some kind of memory leak in the code due to that its happening. You can use instrument to analyse that https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/01/25/ios-memory-leak-xcode/

Comment: For sure, you have a memory leak, you have a strong reference to a variable, I recommend to you to learn how to use Instruments to find memory leaks, you can find tutorials in YouTube.